# What's new in the latest release?

Tags: support, stackexchange

I noticed one nice feature today (move your mouse over tags in question list) and apparently it's new.

Is there any "what's new" file maintained somewhere where we could follow features added in new releases?

I think SE websites are a good example of great design and some word about new releases could be interesting for programmers like us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) question on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) catalogs all announced and undocumented changes to the system.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks